# Lenovo ThinkPad E14 hangs on boot about every third time - Xubuntu 22.04

Tags: boot, thinkpad, 22.04

Two months ago I bought a Lenovo ThinkPad E14 and installed Xubuntu 22.04. It ran perfect for about one month. Then it startet hang on cold boot about every third time. When I make a hard reset it usually startup without problems.
I have run the Lenovo built-in diagnostics multiple times with no errors reported.

Here you have parts of kern.log for a failed boot:

```
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-39-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-069) (gcc (Ubuntu 11.2.0-19ubuntu1) 11.2.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #42-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 23:42:32 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-39.42-generic 5.15.35)
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-39-generic root=UUID=87f8204c-04db-463d-9667-55f27b0bfff9 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] signal: max sigframe size: 1776


Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.70 by Lenovo
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: ACPI=0xcc1fd000 ACPI 2.0=0xcc1fd014 SMBIOS=0xc7c68000 SMBIOS 3.0=0xc7c5b000 TPMFinalLog=0xcb01e000 MEMATTR=0xc1558018 ESRT=0xc2e38918 MOKvar=0xc155b000 RNG=0xc7d7cf98 TPMEventLog=0x99746018
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] efi: seeding entropy pool
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] random: fast init done
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.3.0 present.
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: LENOVO 20Y7006XMX/20Y7006XMX, BIOS R1OET30W (1.09 ) 11/05/2021
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration using PIT
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000000] tsc: Detected 2096.040 MHz processor
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000012] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000014] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000019] last_pfn = 0x3ee300 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000291] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.000545] last_pfn = 0xce000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004031] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x00000000c2e38918 to 0x00000000c2e389c8.
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004037] e820: update [mem 0xc2e38000-0xc2e38fff] usable ==> reserved
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004048] e820: update [mem 0xc155b000-0xc155bfff] usable ==> reserved
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004062] Using GB pages for direct mapping
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004543] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004544] RAMDISK: [mem 0x3c477000-0x3fffdfff]
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    0.004549] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled


Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.905939] [drm] add ip block number 9 <jpeg_v2_0>
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.905953] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Fetched VBIOS from VFCT
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.905955] amdgpu: ATOM BIOS: 113-LUCIENNE-016
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907144] [drm] VCN decode is enabled in VM mode
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907146] [drm] VCN encode is enabled in VM mode
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907147] [drm] JPEG decode is enabled in VM mode
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907179] [drm] vm size is 262144 GB, 4 levels, block size is 9-bit, fragment size is 9-bit
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907185] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: VRAM: 1024M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F43FFFFFFF (1024M used)
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907187] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: GART: 1024M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000003FFFFFFF
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907189] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: AGP: 267419648M 0x000000F800000000 - 0x0000FFFFFFFFFFFF
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907194] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=1024M, BAR=1024M
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907195] [drm] RAM width 128bits DDR4
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907250] [drm] amdgpu: 1024M of VRAM memory ready
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907252] [drm] amdgpu: 3072M of GTT memory ready.
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907258] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 262144, num gpu pages 262144
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907370] [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.907371] [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F400900000
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.908515] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: PSP runtime database doesn't exist
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.911890] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x0101001F
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.912484] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.16 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 3
Jun 20 10:41:46 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    2.912491] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.570982] ucsi_acpi: probe of USBC000:00 failed with error -5
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.611243] [drm] reserve 0x400000 from 0xf43f800000 for PSP TMR
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.631039] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0: Link is Down
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.635932] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.642503] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648002] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648068] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648069] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648078] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648081] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.648087] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.653960] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.654230] usb 1-3: Found UVC 1.10 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6be)
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.655547] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000c lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8822
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.657533] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=3
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.657541] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822cu_fw.bin
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.657862] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8822cu_config.bin
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.658212] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: cfg_sz 6, total sz 35086
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.660641] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated C as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/input/input15
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.661720] usb 1-3: Found UVC 1.50 device Integrated Camera (04f2:b6be)
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.663273] input: Integrated Camera: Integrated I as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.3/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/input/input16
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.663362] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.699155] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.708259] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.708262] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.708988] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is initialized successfully!
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.710261] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.711199] [drm] Display Core initialized with v3.2.149!
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.711733] [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x0101001F
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.734643] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.1: bound 0000:04:00.0 (ops amdgpu_dm_audio_component_bind_ops [amdgpu])
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.747132] loop11: detected capacity change from 0 to 8
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.755039] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.755043] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.755048] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.921537] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Jun 20 10:41:47 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.921559] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.923125] kfd kfd: amdgpu: Allocated 3969056 bytes on gart
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    3.965566] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: fw version 0x19b76d7d
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.093377] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.559964] rtw_8822ce 0000:03:00.0: start vif a8:93:4a:de:75:ab on port 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575570] memmap_init_zone_device initialised 262144 pages in 4ms
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575582] amdgpu: HMM registered 1024MB device memory
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575626] amdgpu: SRAT table not found
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575627] amdgpu: Virtual CRAT table created for GPU
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575723] amdgpu: Topology: Add dGPU node [0x164c:0x1002]
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575727] kfd kfd: amdgpu: added device 1002:164c
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.575809] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SE 1, SH per SE 1, CU per SH 8, active_cu_number 7
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578169] [drm] fb mappable at 0x3F0CD3000
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578172] [drm] vram apper at 0x3F0000000
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578173] [drm] size 8294400
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578173] [drm] fb depth is 24
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578174] [drm]    pitch is 7680
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578244] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578325] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.578331] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598893] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598898] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598900] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598901] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598902] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598905] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598906] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598907] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598908] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598910] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598911] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598912] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598914] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598915] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.598916] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
Jun 20 10:41:48 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    4.600927] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.42.0 20150101 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 0
Jun 20 10:41:49 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    5.900494] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:49 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    5.900505] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Jun 20 10:41:49 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    5.900510] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787036] general protection fault, probably for non-canonical address 0xe6fadebc1e84a053: 0000 [#1] SMP NOPTI
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787154] CPU: 5 PID: 1360 Comm: Xorg:sh0 Not tainted 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787232] Hardware name: LENOVO 20Y7006XMX/20Y7006XMX, BIOS R1OET30W (1.09 ) 11/05/2021
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787310] RIP: 0010:efifb_destroy+0x84/0xa0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787363] Code: e4 01 75 18 48 8d bb 60 02 00 00 e8 a6 c8 fe ff 5b 41 5c 5d c3 e8 ac fc b9 ff eb d0 48 8b 83 00 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 a0 d8 e7 b4 <48> 8b 50 10 48 8b 70 08 e8 5f 81 9c ff eb cb 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787534] RSP: 0018:ffff9eb381cd7c10 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787587] RAX: e6fadebc1e84a043 RBX: ffff904140baa000 RCX: 000000f900000000
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787657] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000004 RDI: ffffffffb4e7d8a0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787724] RBP: ffff9eb381cd7c20 R08: 00000000000000f9 R09: 0000000000000064
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787792] R10: ffff9eb381cd7c60 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787859] R13: ffff904140baa010 R14: ffff904147d912e0 R15: ffff9041405129c0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.787927] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90441ef40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788004] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788060] CR2: 000055ba4fcd2640 CR3: 0000000351210000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788129] Call Trace:
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788156]  <TASK>
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788180]  put_fb_info+0x35/0x50
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788220]  fb_release+0x5f/0x70
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788258]  __fput+0x9f/0x260
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788293]  ____fput+0xe/0x10
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788326]  task_work_run+0x6d/0xa0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788366]  do_exit+0x21b/0x3c0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788403]  do_group_exit+0x3b/0xb0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788443]  get_signal+0x150/0x900
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788481]  arch_do_signal_or_restart+0xda/0x100
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788531]  ? do_futex+0x13d/0x1d0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788569]  ? __x64_sys_futex+0x78/0x1e0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788612]  exit_to_user_mode_loop+0xc4/0x160
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788660]  exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x9c/0xb0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788708]  syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788758]  do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788796]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x84/0xb0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788846]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788895]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788934]  ? exit_to_user_mode_prepare+0x84/0xb0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.788984]  ? syscall_exit_to_user_mode+0x27/0x50
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789033]  ? do_syscall_64+0x69/0xc0
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789072]  ? irqentry_exit+0x19/0x30
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789113]  ? exc_page_fault+0x89/0x160
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789154]  ? asm_exc_page_fault+0x8/0x30
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789199]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xae
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789252] RIP: 0033:0x7f28755ca197
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789291] Code: Unable to access opcode bytes at RIP 0x7f28755ca16d.
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789353] RSP: 002b:00007f285bffe850 EFLAGS: 00000246 ORIG_RAX: 00000000000000ca
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789426] RAX: fffffffffffffe00 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: 00007f28755ca197
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789494] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000189 RDI: 000055c021c8838c
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789561] RBP: 000055c021c88360 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 00000000ffffffff
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789629] R10: 0000000000000000 R11: 0000000000000246 R12: 0000000000000000
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789696] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: 0000000000000013 R15: 000055c021c8838c
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789766]  </TASK>
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789790] Modules linked in: rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg bnep btusb uvcvideo btrtl btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc btintel videobuf2_memops videobuf2_v4l2 bluetooth videobuf2_common videodev ecdh_generic mc ecc intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common amdgpu snd_ctl_led snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg snd_intel_sdw_acpi snd_hda_codec edac_mce_amd snd_hda_core snd_hwdep kvm_amd rtw88_8822ce rtw88_8822c iommu_v2 kvm snd_pcm gpu_sched rtw88_pci drm_ttm_helper crct10dif_pclmul rtw88_core ghash_clmulni_intel ttm snd_seq_midi drm_kms_helper aesni_intel snd_seq_midi_event cec snd_rawmidi rc_core crypto_simd mac80211 nls_iso8859_1 joydev input_leds snd_seq cryptd thinkpad_acpi think_lmi i2c_algo_bit nvram snd_pci_acp5x snd_seq_device rapl serio_raw wmi_bmof firmware_attributes_class efi_pstore fb_sys_fops ledtrig_audio snd_rn_pci_acp3x ucsi_acpi snd_timer syscopyarea cfg80211 sysfillrect typec_ucsi sysimgblt libarc4 snd ccp
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.789905]  snd_pci_acp3x k10temp typec soundcore platform_profile mac_hid sch_fq_codel ipmi_devintf ipmi_msghandler msr parport_pc ppdev lp drm parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 psmouse nvme r8169 xhci_pci crc32_pclmul i2c_piix4 xhci_pci_renesas nvme_core realtek wmi video i2c_scmi
Jun 20 10:41:52 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.790959] ---[ end trace f675c0ed86b56824 ]---
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969066] RIP: 0010:efifb_destroy+0x84/0xa0
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969128] Code: e4 01 75 18 48 8d bb 60 02 00 00 e8 a6 c8 fe ff 5b 41 5c 5d c3 e8 ac fc b9 ff eb d0 48 8b 83 00 04 00 00 48 c7 c7 a0 d8 e7 b4 <48> 8b 50 10 48 8b 70 08 e8 5f 81 9c ff eb cb 66 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969300] RSP: 0018:ffff9eb381cd7c10 EFLAGS: 00010202
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969353] RAX: e6fadebc1e84a043 RBX: ffff904140baa000 RCX: 000000f900000000
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969422] RDX: 0000000000000000 RSI: 0000000000000004 RDI: ffffffffb4e7d8a0
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969489] RBP: ffff9eb381cd7c20 R08: 00000000000000f9 R09: 0000000000000064
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969556] R10: ffff9eb381cd7c60 R11: 0000000000000000 R12: 0000000000000001
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969624] R13: ffff904140baa010 R14: ffff904147d912e0 R15: ffff9041405129c0
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.969692] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff90441ef40000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.970891] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.972001] CR2: 000055ba4fcd2640 CR3: 0000000106010000 CR4: 0000000000350ee0
Jun 20 10:41:53 e14xubu2204 kernel: [    8.973094] Fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed!
Jun 20 10:41:56 e14xubu2204 kernel: [   12.902476] kauditd_printk_skb: 25 callbacks suppressed
Jun 20 10:41:56 e14xubu2204 kernel: [   12.902480] audit: type=1400 audit(1655714516.971:36): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/usr/sbin/cups-browsed" pid=1459 comm="cups-browsed" capability=23  capname="sys_nice"
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating to the latest system bios version seems to have solved the problem, even though I can't see anything in the change log than I can relate to this issue.